# dplyr top_n() - Suppress status message?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some R code that looks as follows:

```
rawList <- df %>% select(colIndex) %>% top_n(rows)
```

This executes as I would expect, but when it runs, I get output that looks like this:

```
Selecting by ReadTime
```

I just recently added the top_n() code and never saw this message before adding this function. Now I'm starting to see it. I assume it's comming from the top_n() function, and I cannot find a way to suppress this message.

Comment: Maybe `help("suppressMessages")`.

Comment: @lmo - I don't want to suppress all messages like this, that might be coming from other functions. Just this particular message coming from top_n().

Comment: @MrFlick - Works perfectly. If you want to create this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @RandyMinder I was wrong about using 1 as an index. You need to use a column name to get the right behavior. I've put that in my answer.

Comment: @MrFlick - Using 1 as an index works for me.

Comment: @RandyMinder How about `data.frame(x = c(10, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1)) %>% top_n(2,1)`. I get the values 10 and 1 returned when i would expect 10 and 6. It doesn't give an error, but it doesn't return the values you want.

Comment: @MrFlick - Ah yes, I see what you mean, thank you.

Comment: Ahh! I was looking for `%>% head(n)` not `%>% top_n(n)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That message appears when you don't explicitly pass a `wt` parameter to `top_n` to tell it which column to use select the top values for.

Compare

```
dd <- data.frame(x = c(10, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1)) 
dd %>% top_n(2)
# Selecting by x
dd %>% top_n(2, x) # use column name
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I didn't specify a wt because there is only a single variable in the data frame, so I didn't think it necessary.